# Passing data back from child view controller

Tags: objective-c, uicontainerview, childviewcontroller, parentviewcontroller

I am a beginner, and I have a project in which I need to pass data back from a childviewcontroller. Specifically, I have a picker view in my container and I want to be able to use it to select an option (say to simplify just a color to chose from an array of ten colours). Then I would like to be able to access the chosen color in my parent view controller and do something with it. I have researched this for a couple of days now and the closest answer to what I am looking for I found in a related question on S.O. Here it is:

"Regarding passing value to the containerView controller, you can make a property in the ChildViewController of the value you want it to be passed. Then in your ParentViewController do something like the following:

```
self.ChildViewController.yourProperty = yourValue
```

The opposite can be done in 4 ways:

You can make a delegate protocol to communicate the data between your controllers.

You can post a notification in your ChildViewController and add the parent controller as an observer.

You can use KVO.

And the easiest way out, you can make a property in your parentviewController and access it like the following:"

```
((YourParentViewControllerClassType *)self.parentViewController).yourParentProperty = TheValueYouWant;
```

Now, I would like to try the fourth option first as delegation, kvo and so on are options I have read about but not ready to tackle yet. What I would need help with is the last option.

Say I had a property in my child view controller where I store the chosen color. Something like:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property NSString *ChosenColorInChildVC;

@end
```

And then, later on:

```
self.ChosenColorInChildVC = [self pickerView:myPickerView titleForRow:[myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:1] forComponent:1]];
```

how would I pass that value using the proposed:

```
((YourParentViewControllerClassType *)self.parentViewController).yourParentProperty = TheValueYouWant;
```

Can someone dumb it down a little further for me? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to explain you with an example how delegation works.

Edit your ChildViewController.h like this:

```
@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate; 

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak)id <ChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate <NSObject > 

- (void) passValue:(UIColor *) theValue;

@end
```

On your ChildViewController.m when you want to pass something back to the ParentViewController , do like this:

```
 - (void) myMethod
 {
   [delegate passValue:[UIColor redColor]]; // you pass the value here
 }
```

On your ParentViewController.h

```
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <ChildViewControllerDelegate >  // you adopt the protocol
{
}
```

On your ParentViewController.m:

```
- (void) passValue:(UIColor *) theValue
   {
      //here you receive the color passed from ChildViewController
   }
```

Now be careful. Everything will work only if you set the delegate.
So when you declare ChildViewController inside your ParentViewController class, do like this:

```
ChildViewController * controller = [[ChildViewController alloc]initWithiNibName:@"ChildViewController"];
controller.delegate = self; //without this line the code won't work!
```

Comment: Hi metronic. Thanks for this, it's been a huge help. I have done everything you said and (I think) understood the logic behind most of it. Except for the last bit you wrote: "On your ParentViewController.m: -(void) passValue:(UIColor *) theValue { //here you receive the color passed from ChildViewController}" I understand more or less the idea behind it, but how does it actually work in practice. Say I have chosen red in my container. how would I access it in my parent by using this method? something like: UIColor *myReceivedColor = [self passValue:???];

Comment: No, you'll receive the data inside the method - (void) passValue:(UIColor *) theValue;  Put a breakpoint in that method to be sure that it's working, you can access it like this: UIColor *myReceivedColor = theValue;

Comment: OK. Sorry about this. I am not familiar at all with the concept of "receiving values" inside a method. So, to make sure I understand you. Do I need to write anything inside the method     -(void) passValue:(UIColor *) theValue{} in my Parent? And if I want to access the color in my parent... I've tried to write litteraly UIColor *myReceivedColor = theValue; and it comes back with "used of undeclared identifier: "theValue". I have also tried UIColor *myReceivedValue = [self passValue:theValue];

Comment: I have also tried this [self passValue:[self.controller.colors objectAtIndex:[self.controller.myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]];

Comment: I think I know why it's not working. Your line: ChildViewController * controller = [[ChildViewController alloc]initWithiNibName:@"ChildViewController"]; prompts an error: no visible @interface for "ChildViewController" declares the selector "initWithNibName'

Answer (score 0):

@metronic is right; use delegation.

Also typically you will include the sender in your delegate methods:

```
-(void) childViewController:(ChildViewController*)viewController passValue:(UIColor*) theValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Noted: this is very important.

Write protocol declaration code above the #import lines e.g.

@protocol -----

@end

import ----

@interface classname ---